# I finished my first website and don't know how to upload it live

Tags: php, html, ftp, publish, host

I finished my first website with HTML, CSS, Jquery and a little PHP contact form. How do I get it live? I already bought a domain and hosting for a year.

I prefer not to use wordpress as I dont know how to convert html to wordpress.I have heard of FTP but dont understand it.

Comment: "I already bought a domain and hosting for a year." — We don't know what facilities your hosting company provides for uploading files. Ask their technical support service for help.

Comment: What's your name of hosting server?

Comment: do u have a web host?

Answer (score 0):

So you own a domain already which is the hardest part. Some websites like GoDaddy.com offer their own FTP (File Transfer Protocol) which is what you need to transfer your files to the server. There should be some sort of tutorial if you google based on who you purchased your domain from.

If the web host does not offer a free FTP there are free ones such as FileZilla (which I prefer). Once you download one of these you need to enter your exact web domain, username you used to create the website, and the password for it, then all you need to do is drag and drop your files.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.